# Combine using Python multiprocessing ThreadPool + Pool (for process), process does not work sometimes

Tags: python

I'm using ThreadPool for IO-intensive work (such as loading data) while fork a process within the thread if there is CPU-intensive calculation needed. This is my workaround to the GIL problem (anyway, this is not my key problem here).

My problem is: when running my code, sometimes, although a process is folked, it looks always in sleeping status (not even run my calculation). Thus, it causes blocking since the code calls join to wait for result (or error). Note that the problem doesn't always happen, just occasionally.

My running environment is: linux centos 7.3, anaconda 5.1.0 (with built-in python 3.6.4). And note that: i failed to reproduce the issue with the same code on windows.

the following is the simplified code, which can reproduce the issue on linux:

```
import logging
import time
import random
import os
import threading

from multiprocessing.pool import Pool, ThreadPool


class Task(object):
    def __init__(self, func, *args) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.func = func
        self.args = args


class ConcurrentExecutor(object):
    def __init__(self, spawn_count=1) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.spawn_count = spawn_count

    def fork(self, task):
        result = None
        print('Folk started: %s' % task.args)

        pool = Pool(processes=1)
        try:
            handle = pool.apply_async(task.func, task.args)
            pool.close()
            result = handle.get()

            print('Folk completed: %s' % task.args)
        except Exception as err:
            print('Fork failure: FOLK%s' % task.args)
            raise err
        finally:
            pool.terminate()

        return result

    def spawn(self, tasks):
        results = []
        try:
            print('Spawn started')
            handles = []
            pool = ThreadPool(processes=self.spawn_count)

            for task in tasks:
                handles.append(pool.apply_async(task.func, task.args))

            pool.close()
            pool.join()

            print('all done')
            for handle in handles:
                results.append(handle.get(10))

            print('Spawn completed')
        except Exception as err:
            print('Spawn failure')
            raise err

        return results


def foo_proc(i):
    print(i)
    result=i*i
    time.sleep(1)
    return result


def foo(i):
    executor = ConcurrentExecutor(2)
    try:
        result = executor.fork(Task(foo_proc, i))
    except Exception as err:
        result = 'ERROR'
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor = ConcurrentExecutor(4)
    tasks = []

    for i in range(1, 10):
        tasks.append(Task(foo, i))

    start = time.time()
    print(executor.spawn(tasks))
    end = time.time()
    print(end - start)
```

The following shows an example of running result:

```
[appadmin@168-61-40-47 test]$ python test.py 
7312
Spawn started
Folk started: 1
Folk started: 2
Folk started: 3
Folk started: 4
4
2
1
3
Folk completed: 4
Folk completed: 2
Folk completed: 1
Folk completed: 3
Folk started: 5
Folk started: 6
Folk started: 7
5
Folk started: 8
7
8
Folk completed: 5
Folk completed: 7
Folk completed: 8
Folk started: 9
9
Folk completed: 9
```

You may see the code was stuck since process "6" was folked but never do the work. Meanwhile, i can see two python processes, which is supposed to be only 1 process at last if everything runs correctly:

```
[user@x-x-x-x x]$ ps -aux | grep python
user  7312  0.1  0.0 1537216 13524 pts/0   Sl+  22:23   0:02 python test.py
user  7339  0.0  0.0 1545444 10604 pts/0   S+   22:23   0:00 python test.py
```

Could anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Let's start with the glaringly obvious - why are creating a process pool only to spawn one process in it and immediately destroy the whole pool after the process finishes? Also, why are you closing the pool before your process even has the chance to return anything?

Comment: Thanks for help! for your 1st question, i agree that it's not graceful. however, at least i think it should work well. Not sure what's the cause. Is it stability problem when using in this way because pool keeps creating/destroying? However, why it works well on windows? For your 2nd question, this just follows the manual which says calling close method first to reject any new requests to the pool.

Comment: `multiprocessing.Pool` adds a lot of overhead to manage its pool so that was my prime suspect of a process-lock that happens in your case. If it always works on Windows and always fails on Linux, the issue might be due to the multiprocessing strategy (a whole new process vs fork) but it would warrant further debugging to see what actually happens with the process given that the called `foo_proc()` doesn't leave much room to lock itself (maybe, just maybe the STDOUT access from the `print()` call could).